# Why is it throwing an Django- Reverse query name SystemCheckError?

Tags: python, django

I am a newbie to Django, While running the django application using `python3 manage.py runserver`
Because of the way I have created the model I am getting an error like

```
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
database.LeadsStatus.company_id: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'LeadsStatus.company_id' clashes with reverse query name for 'LeadsStatus.companies'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'LeadsStatus.company_id' or 'LeadsStatus.companies'.
database.Users.id: (fields.E007) Primary keys must not have null=True.
        HINT: Set null=False on the field, or remove primary_key=True argument.

System check identified 2 issues (0 silenced).
```

This is how I've created model.

```
class LeadsStatus(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
    company_id = models.ForeignKey('Companies', null=False, db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    users_id = models.IntegerField()
    assign_date = models.DateTimeField()
    companies = models.OneToOneField('Companies', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I believe the error might be because of the way I have created a OneToOneField. How do I solve this error. Please help me understand. Thanks

Comment: Do you need both a Foreign Key and a OneToOne relation to the Companies table? (are you pointing to two instances of Companies or just one?). Also you have another error on your User table where you are setting a field as the Primary Key and also allowing null value which is not possible.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I removed the error which was on Users table. Yes I need both a foreign key and a one to one relation to the Companies table

Comment: Hint: you can omit the field `id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True)`, as it is added automatically by Django (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need 2 foreing keys to the model `Companies`, then you need to set the option [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) to distinguish them.

You can change your class to, for example, this:

```
class LeadsStatus(models.Model):
    ...
    company_id = models.ForeignKey(
        'Companies',
        null=False,
        db_index=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='leadsstatus_1_set')
    ...
    companies = models.OneToOneField(
        'Companies',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='leadsstatus')
```

You could also set `related_name` on just one of these 2 fields, as long as it is different from the default value of `leadsstatus_set`.